# working with directories in POSIX with C

Tags: c, unix, directory, posix

I will go ahead and say this is a homework assignment for an intro to Linux class. I would not be posting it without extensive attempts on my own,  and seeing as I am a distance student this semester, I cannot make it to campus for tutoring. I need some help finding out what the issue is.

Essentially the assignment asks us to make a program that serves the same basic function as the `pwd` command in POSIX, to show the absolute path for the current directory. We are to use three functions along with main. We are not to use the `getcwd` command as well. I'll list them and their purpose

- `inum_to_filename`: Accepts three arguments (inode number to translate, a pointer to a buffer where the name is written, and the size of the buffer). Returns nothing. It is to:

  1. Open the current directory,
  2. Read the first directory entry,
  3. If the inode of the current directory matches the one passed in, copy name to buffer and return.
  4. Otherwise read the next directory entry and repeat the previous step.
- `filename_to_inum`: Accepts one argument (a `char *` representing the filename). It returns the corresponding inode number. It is to:

  1. Read the information from the files inode into a structure in memory.
  2. If there is any problem, display the appropriate error.
  3. Return the inode number from the structure.
- `display_path`: Accepts one argument (inode from the current working directory). It returns nothing. It is to:

  1. Create an array of characters to use as a buffer for the name of the directory.
  2. Get the inode for the parent directory using `filename_to_inode`.
  3. If the parent inode is equal to the current inode, we have reached root and can return.
  4. Otherwise, change to the parent directory and use `inum_to_filename` to find the name for the inode that was passed into the function. Use the buffer from step 1 to store it.
  5. Recursively call `display_path` to display the absolute path.

Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>

void inum_to_filename (int inode_arg, char *pathBuffer, int size_arg) {
    DIR *dir_ptr = opendir(".");
    struct dirent *dirent_ptr = readdir(dir_ptr);
    int counter = 0;

    while (counter != 1) {
        if (inode_arg == dirent_ptr->d_ino) {

            strcat(pathBuffer, "/");
            strcat(pathBuffer, dirent_ptr->d_name);

            counter = counter + 1;
            return;

        } else {
            dirent_ptr = readdir(dir_ptr);
        }
    }

    closedir(dir_ptr);
}

int filename_to_inum (char *src) {
    int res = 0;
    struct stat info;
    int result = stat(src, &info);

    if (result != 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Cannot stat ");
        perror(src);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    } else {
        res = info.st_ino;
    }

    return res;
} 

void display_path (int ino_src) {
    int bufSize = 4096;
    char pathBuffer[bufSize];
    int ino_prnt = filename_to_inum("..");

    if (ino_src == ino_prnt) {
        //print for test
        inum_to_filename(ino_src, pathBuffer, bufSize);
        printf("%s", pathBuffer);
        return;
    } else {
        //print for test
        chdir("..");
        inum_to_filename(ino_src, pathBuffer, bufSize);
        display_path(ino_prnt);
        printf("%s", pathBuffer);
    }
}

int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int c_ino = filename_to_inum(".");
    display_path(c_ino);
    printf("\n");
}
```

As of right now it is displaying "/./MyName" with MyName being my personal named directory on the server. It is the directory I am running the program from. When using pwd I return "/home/MyName". I'm not really sure what my next step to getting the absolute path correct is.

Comment: Here's a hint. You're calling display_path recursively. What happens with the pathBuffer variable in each call and after each call returns?

Comment: Yuck.  I'm not sure that I understand how those utility functions are to be used in the processing.  I'm also not convinced that the inode number alone is sufficient if there are multiple file systems involved.  The `inum_to_filename()` function outline doesn't take into account the possibility of the inode number it is giving not appearing in the current directory.  The basic technique is normally 'find the inode number of the current directory; open the parent directory, reading entries and find the entry with the inode that matches the inode of the current directory.  Repeat.

Comment: You need to ensure you close the directory you opened before returning from `inum_to_filename()` or you leak DIR descriptors.  (Incidentally, the inode of the parent of the root directory is also the inode of the root directory.  That is, the inode of `/.` is the same as `/..` and it is normally inode number 2.)

Comment: @MichaelAlbers It would be re-created during each call? And in this instance, since its called twice, the second creation overwrites the first one?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler is the closedir call at the end of inum_to_filename not accomplishing that?

Comment: @Monobus Correct. inum_to_filename will update it, but since it's a plain old local variable it will just "go away" and the contents will be lost. A quick fix, and maybe not the best one, would be to make it static.

Comment: @Monobus: only in the case when the function fails.  There's an early return in the `while` loop that is used when the function succeeds (most of the time) and it does not close the directory.  Always look at every exit path.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I added the closedir() inside the loop so in both cases it closes the stream.

Comment: @MichaelAlbers I see what you mean. I have made it static, but all it served was to reverse the orber of the array, so now it displays /MyName/.

My biggest question is why it is returning the relative '.' instead of the actual name of the parent directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code is mostly set up to print one name at a time in the correct order, so the primary problem is the use of `strcat()` rather than `strcpy()`.  Also, detecting when you're in the root directory at the start is important; if you don't, you can end up with `/.` or something similar (depending on exactly how you coordinate the printing) when the current directory is the root directory.

This version of your code has:

- Squished the loop in `inum_to_filename()`, but also added error reporting.  Remember, a process can be run in a directory which it does not have permission to get to (it requires a setuid program, usually — although permissions could be changed after the program is launched).  In that case, it may fail to open `..` (or `.`).
- Lost variable `count`; it wasn't serving a useful purpose.  Using the assign-and-test idiom allows the code to contain a single call to `readdir()`.
- Use `strcpy()` instead of `strcat()`.
- Use type `ino_t` to store inode numbers.  Use `size_t` for sizes.
- Reduce number of intermediate variables in `filename_to_inum()`.
- Note that the code in the `if (ino_src == ino_prnt)` statement body is for the root directory; in the absence of the testing print, it would do nothing.
- Note that the printing in the `else` part is a major part of the operations, not just test printing.
- Error check `chdir("..");`
- Detect root in `main()`.
- Observe that this code is not directly suitable for rewriting into a function because it changes the process's current directory to `/` when it succeeds.

Revised code:

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h>

static void inum_to_filename(ino_t inode_arg, char *pathBuffer, size_t size_arg)
{
    assert(size_arg > 0);
    DIR *dir_ptr = opendir(".");
    if (dir_ptr == 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to open directory '.' (%d: %s)\n", errno, strerror(errno));
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    struct dirent *dirent_ptr;

    while ((dirent_ptr = readdir(dir_ptr)) != 0)
    {
        if (inode_arg == dirent_ptr->d_ino)
        {
            if (strlen(dirent_ptr->d_name) >= size_arg)
            {
                fprintf(stderr, "File name %s too long (%zu vs %zu max)\n",
                        dirent_ptr->d_name, strlen(dirent_ptr->d_name), size_arg);
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }
            strcpy(pathBuffer, dirent_ptr->d_name);
            break;
        }
    }

    closedir(dir_ptr);
}

static ino_t filename_to_inum(char *src)
{
    struct stat info;

    if (stat(src, &info) != 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Cannot stat ");
        perror(src);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    return info.st_ino;
}

static void display_path(ino_t ino_src)
{
    size_t bufSize = 4096;
    char pathBuffer[bufSize];
    ino_t ino_prnt = filename_to_inum("..");

    if (ino_src == ino_prnt)
    {
        // print for test
        inum_to_filename(ino_src, pathBuffer, bufSize);
        printf("%s", "(root): /\n");
    }
    else
    {
        // print for real
        if (chdir("..") != 0)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "Failed to chdir to .. (%d: %s)\n",
                    errno, strerror(errno));
        }
        inum_to_filename(ino_src, pathBuffer, bufSize);
        display_path(ino_prnt);
        printf("/%s", pathBuffer);
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    ino_t c_ino = filename_to_inum(".");
    ino_t r_ino = filename_to_inum("/");
    if (r_ino == c_ino)
        putchar('/');
    else
        display_path(c_ino);
    printf("\n");
}
```

There are undoubtedly other ways to fix this.

<sup>*Caveat: this is giving me some grief when working in `/Volumes/CRUZER/Sub-Directory` which is a memory stick.  It fails to find the inode (`1`, which is surprising) when scanning `/Volumes`, and I've not worked out why.  One of my programs — a `getpwd` implementation — is working fine; another is having a different problem.  I expect I'll get to the bottom of it all.  Testing on Mac OS X 10.10.5 with GCC 5.1.0.*</sup>

Answer (score 1):

this is really nice assignment :). 
I read and tried your code, and it is almost correct. There were two small issues which were causing the incorrect behaviour.

**First issue**

When `display_path` reaches the root folder you don't need to call `inum_to_filename` and print the name of the folder because you have already printed the first folder of the path in the previous iteration. This prevents your code from showing a "./" in the beginning of the path. 
That is, the if condition becomes:

```
 if (ino_src == ino_prnt) {
        return;
    } else {
        chdir("..");
        inum_to_filename(ino_src, pathBuffer, bufSize);
        display_path(ino_prnt);
        printf("%s", pathBuffer);
    }
```

**Second Issue**:

You're not initializing propertly the buffer where you save the name of the directory. This causes random values to be displayed. To solve this issue you can just set the initial value of the buffer to zero by using `memset`.

```
void inum_to_filename (int inode_arg, char *pathBuffer, int size_arg) {
    DIR *dir_ptr = opendir(".");
    struct dirent *dirent_ptr = readdir(dir_ptr);
    int counter = 0;

    memset(pathBuffer, 0, size_arg);

    while (counter != 1) {
     ...
    }

    closedir(dir_ptr);
}
```

Full code working :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>

void inum_to_filename (int inode_arg, char *pathBuffer, int size_arg) {
    DIR *dir_ptr = opendir(".");
    struct dirent *dirent_ptr = readdir(dir_ptr);
    int counter = 0;

    memset(pathBuffer, 0, size_arg);

    while (counter != 1) {
        if (inode_arg == dirent_ptr->d_ino) {

            strcat(pathBuffer, "/");
            strcat(pathBuffer, dirent_ptr->d_name);

            counter = counter + 1;
            return;

        } else {
            dirent_ptr = readdir(dir_ptr);
        }
    }

    closedir(dir_ptr);
}

int filename_to_inum (char *src) {
    int res = 0;
    struct stat info;
    int result = stat(src, &info);

    if (result != 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Cannot stat ");
        perror(src);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    } else {
        res = info.st_ino;
    }

    return res;
} 

/*
  - Create an array of characters to use as a buffer for the name of the directory.
  - Get the inode for the parent directory using filename_to_inode.
  - If the parent inode is equal to the current inode, we have reached root and can return.
  - Otherwise, change to the parent directory and use inum_to_filename to find the name for 
    the inode that was passed into the function. Use the buffer from step 1 to store it.
  - Recursively call display_path to display the absolute path.
*/

void display_path (int ino_src) {
    int bufSize = 4096;
    char pathBuffer[bufSize];
    int ino_prnt = filename_to_inum("..");

    if (ino_src == ino_prnt) {
        return;
    } else {
        chdir("..");
        inum_to_filename(ino_src, pathBuffer, bufSize);
        display_path(ino_prnt);
        printf("%s", pathBuffer);
    }
}

int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int c_ino = filename_to_inum(".");
    display_path(c_ino);
    printf("\n");
}
```

Output :

```
ubuntu@ubuntu-VirtualBox:~/dev$ vi pwd.c 
ubuntu@ubuntu-VirtualBox:~/dev$ gcc pwd.c 
ubuntu@ubuntu-VirtualBox:~/dev$ ./a.out 
/home/ubuntu/dev
ubuntu@ubuntu-VirtualBox:~/dev$ pwd
/home/ubuntu/dev
ubuntu@ubuntu-VirtualBox:~/dev$
```

Comment: That is wonderful! However, when running it on the server, it doesn't go any higher than the MyName directory. I wonder why. Nevertheless, it is progress! Thank you!

Comment: What is your current directory? can you past the full path? Have you tried my full code in the server? it is weird, I tried in my Linux and MacOSx laptop and both worked correctly.

Comment: which file system are you using?

Comment: It is a school server. When running pwd it returns /home/MyName.

Comment: Have you tried in an another directory? Could be related to user privilege?

Comment: That is what I am thinking. I made a folder in MyName and ran it from there, and it returned /MyName/folder.

Comment: you can use `ls -id` to check the inode number of `myName`, `home` and `/`. To be sure they have all different values. This might help to debug the issue

Comment: This problem with generating an incomplete path will probably be mount points — the top-level directory in each mounted file system has inode 2 (usually — my memory stick on a Mac has an inode of 1 for the root of the memory stick), so you're stopping too early.  One way around that (in general) is to track both `st_ino` and `st_dev` and make sure both match.